# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE [silverdb01].[dbo].[info] 
SET [FM] = SUM(a.[MONDAY] - b.[QUOTA]) 
FROM  [silverdb01].[dbo].[info] a,  [silverdb01].[dbo].[quota] b 
WHERE a.[WORK_TYPE]='IN' AND a.[NAME]='KUTHAY'
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> *An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.*

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually want to do that cartesian product?. Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: i use mssql, and i want to substraction between pazartesi and kota which comes from different tables.

Comment: I realize that you want to use two different tables, but do you know that you are not using a `JOIN` condition between them, thus resulting on a cartesian product?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it! And did you **really** want a cartesian product between those two tables, or did you just forget to add the `JOIN` condition between them to your `UPDATE` statement??

Comment: i have 2 different, info and kota table. i want to take the pazartesi and kota of name='alp' and want to substract them and set as FM. I used this type you gave but again giving the same error.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I am guessing that (as other's have pointed out) you don't really want a cartesian on this update so I have added an "id" to the query so you will have to do some modification but this might get you on the right path

```
;with temp as (
    select  a.id, SUM(a.pazartesi - b.kota) as newTotal
    from    [asgdb01].[dbo].[info] a join [asgdb01].[dbo].[kota] b 
          on a.id = b.id
    where   a.work_type='in' and a.name='alp' )
update  a
set     fm = t.newTotal
from    [asgdb01].[dbo].[info] a join temp t on a.id = t.id
```

Comment: I had to group by the ID in temp to make it work using count instead of sum. Fantastic answer though.

Comment: ＋１  [CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) being an elegant and good performance solution in contrast to the [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937315/) other ways that are using `CROSS` or inline subqueries.