# Aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Receiving an error stating an aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement. Any ideas?

```
 UPDATE STOCK SET STOCK.LPURCHDATE = MAX(INVTRANS.TRANS_DATE)
 FROM STOCK
 INNER JOIN INVTRANS ON STOCK.NUMBER = INVTRANS.NUMBER
 WHERE INVTRANS.NOTATION <> 'Product Merging' AND
(INVTRANS.TRANSTYPE = 'D' OR INVTRANS.TRANSTYPE = 'A')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738900/an-aggregate-may-not-appear-in-the-set-list-of-an-update-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
UPDATE STOCK SET STOCK.LPURCHDATE = (select MAX(INVTRANS.TRANS_DATE) FROM INVTRANS
                                WHERE INVTRANS.NOTATION <> 'Product Merging' 
                                AND  INVTRANS.TRANSTYPE IN('D','A') 
                                AND STOCK.NUMBER = INVTRANS.NUMBER)
```

**OR**

```
;with tmp as(
SELECT STOCK.NUMBER, MAX(INVTRANS.TRANS_DATE) MX
 FROM STOCK
 INNER JOIN INVTRANS ON STOCK.NUMBER = INVTRANS.NUMBER
 WHERE INVTRANS.NOTATION <> 'Product Merging' AND
(INVTRANS.TRANSTYPE = 'D' OR INVTRANS.TRANSTYPE = 'A')
)
 UPDATE STOCK SET STOCK.LPURCHDATE = MX
 FROM STOCK
 INNER JOIN TMP ON STOCK.NUMBER = TMP.NUMBER
```