# SQL Update Query with aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, aggregate

I have 2 tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inventory](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
[SerialNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Quantity] [decimal](12, 3) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryDetails](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[InventoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Quantity] [decimal](10, 3) NOT NULL)
```

I wanna execute query like:

```
Update I set Quantity=Sum(ID.Quantity)
from Inventory I
Inner Join inserted ID on I.ID=ID.InventoryID
```

SQL Servers gives this error: 
`An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`

what is the true way to do this? Do I Need Group By Clause?

Comment: First google result: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-157.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738900/an-aggregate-may-not-appear-in-the-set-list-of-an-update-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the code is used in a trigger on the InventoryDetails table (because it uses the special inserted table). It would have been nice to specify it in the question.

It is a limitation of SQL Server. It can be overcome by using subqueries.

```
UPDATE I SET Quantity=ID.Sum_Quantity
FROM Inventory I
INNER JOIN (SELECT InventoryID, SUM(Quantity) AS Sum_Quantity 
            FROM inserted GROUP BY InventoryID) ID ON I.ID=ID.InventoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify a bit your update sql script and I think it should be like:

```
update Inventory as I
set I.Quantity = (select sum(ID.Quantity) from InventoryDetails as ID)
where I.ID = (select IDS.ID from InventoryDetails as IDS where IDS.ID = I.ID)
```

A little explanation:

> select sum(ID.Quantity) from InventoryDetails as ID

this select does your aggregation that you want.

> where I.ID = (select IDS.ID from InventoryDetails as IDS where IDS.ID
>   = I.ID)

And this *simulates* your inner join. (Please correct me here if I'm wrong, thanks).